# mysql conditional insert - if not exists insert

Tags: mysql, insert, conditional-statements

Is there a query that will just check for the record and if it doesn't exists insert? I don't want to on duplicate update or replace. Looking for a one query solution, looked at other answer but not really what I was hoping for.

Table:

```
name|value|id
------------------
phill|person|12345
```

pseudo query:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(name='phill', value='person', id=12345) INSERT INTO table_name
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit?

Is id the only unique field? (in a quick and dirty way you could use a unique index and it will fail if you try and insert a row with a duplicate value).

Do the name and value have to be unique as well?

Comment: all three values are unique and must not be empty. Id has an index, the name and value should be different as well but the id is a must

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `REPLACE` - works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

```
-- For your example query
REPLACE INTO table_name(name, value, id) VALUES
('phill', 'person', 12345)
```

Edit:  Since you can't use REPLACE another option is to: set constraint indexes for the table data (primary key, uniqueness) and use INSERT IGNORE

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name
SET name = 'phill',
    value = 'person',
    id = 12345;
```

Comment: Yes I understand the functionality but my user only has access to SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE. but I'm trying to stay away from UPDATE and I don't know if I have permission for the REPLACE function

Comment: does the INSERT IGNORE delete and add the record again? or does it just skip it if found and insert if not found?

Answer (score 2):

How about doing an insert from a select query which has a sub-query to only return a row if the row does not already exist?

Pseudocode:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_FOO (...)
SELECT @VAR1, VAR2 ...
FROM DUMMYTABLE -- THIS TABLE SHOULD CONTAIN 1 RECORD OF ANYTHING
                -- IN CASE THE FROM IS REQUIRED
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_FOO WHERE COLUMN1 = @VAR1) = 0
```

This pattern should work, you'll just need to get the syntax correct for MySQL.

Comment: This was useful when dealing with rows that didn't use keys or uniques.