# mysql conditional insert - if not exists insert - multi value insert

Tags: mysql

From my [previous questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223344/mysql-conditional-insert-if-not-exists-insert)n this was the solution I am accepting:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name
SET name = 'phill',
    value = 'person',
    id = 12345;
```

But I also wanted to know if I could be multiple values like this

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name
SET (name = 'phill', value = 'person', id = 12345),
    (name = 'bob', value = 'person', id = 12346);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name(name,value,id) VALUES 
('phill','person',12345),('bob','person',12346)
```

Comment: if id 12345 already exists, does the entire insert fail or only that single row? In other words, if phill exists, will bob still be inserted?

Comment: @alex9311: Only rows that cause error are discarded, not the whole statement .