# How to Check for record existence and do Insert in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

How to Check for record existence and do Insert or Update in MYSQL ?

I  have a script, which has set of Insert statements for multiple tables. Now when i try to execute the Insert statement, i want to do the following:

- Check for the record existence and then do Insert or Update.
- If the Record is not exist do Insert.
- If the Record is already do not do anything.

How to accomplish this ?

Note : The script with Insert Statements are generated programmaticaly using SP

Comment: How you want to check for existence of record? Using primary key? or any other mechanism?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223344/mysql-conditional-insert-if-not-exists-insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INSERT IGNORE` :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name
SET column = value
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what mysqls replace is for

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html