# Mysql conditional insert(With the combined primary key)

Tags: mysql

I have the table with following structure

```
id -- auto increment
name -- unique
group -- integer
Primary key(name,group)
```

I do not want to add the element with the same name and group values.

```
(i.e ("test",1) and ("test",1) should not be inserted.... and 
        ("test",1),("test",2) can be inserted).
```

I want to insert a value if not exist .. I checked the  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223344/mysql-conditional-insert-if-not-exists-insert).

Using the above link it is possible to do the operation , but the problem is it only checks the name as key not combined with group (i.e Insertion of the values("test",1) and ("test",2) is not happening)

How can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem with name column unique ,please remove unique constraint on name column and try `INSERT IGNORE INTO yourTable(name,group)values("test",2)`

Comment: Yes you are right everything works fine after removing the unique key. Thanks for you time to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary key is a composite of `name` and `group`

You can do `INSERT IGNORE`

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO yourTable
SET name = 'test',
    group = 1;
```

As long as both of them are part of your primary key, this should check for their combination

Comment: I already tried this. It only checks the name not the group...(i.e while inserting (test,1) which already exist in the table it works fine(not inserted into the table)...but while giving (test,2) which is a different value from previous it is not getting inserted)

Comment: Then your primary key is probably not a composite of both fields. Cause this will then be against database logic to keep doing that even if they are Primary