# MySQL insert into two fields, if combination of content in this fields is unique

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

i have a mysql table with fields:

appName appVersion

i want to insert content into this fields if combination of appName and appVersion not exist in it.

Comment: Have a look at the answers here: [possible duplicate question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223344/mysql-conditional-insert-if-not-exists-insert

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you have an option:

1. Create unique [index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) by 2 columns `appName`, `appVersion`
2. Use `INSERT IGNORE` - this will skip [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) if the corresponding record already exists in table